# How does three dots followed by variable in an object literal (object spread) work?

Tags: javascript

I have seen this this piece of code a few times in tutorials.

`const foo = {...bar}`

how does the `{...bar}` exactly work?

Comment: this is spread syntax. Read about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator .

Comment: It's a proposal for future javascript, already usable with an experimental transpiler.

Comment: [Rest and spread operators](https://rainsoft.io/how-three-dots-changed-javascript/)

Comment: @Bergi And modern browsers in existence today, like the latest versions  of Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Comment: oh i see and its useable with babel

Comment: @A.J, zer00ne and GolezTrol: no, that's the array spread syntax.